# The $\|x\|$ inside Generalized Gaussian distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, terminology, notation

The  density of generalized Gaussian distribution is
$$ f(x) = c_0\exp\left(-\frac{\|x\|^s}{s}\right), \quad x\in \mathbb{R}^m,  $$.

So, why we are writing $\|x\|$. Is that norm?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\| x \|$ there must mean the usual euclidean norm, that is 
$$
\| x \| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \dotsm + x_m^2}.
$$